# Как отменить выход из программы?

Tags: c#, winforms

Случилась ситуация

```
this.FormClosing += btn_close_Click;

void btn_close_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (MessageBox.Show(this,
    "realy exit?",
    "closing program",
    MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
    MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
       this.Close();
    }
}
```

После модального окна программа все равно выключается.

Подскажите, как исправить.

Comment: посмотрите [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12409529/how-to-prevent-or-block-closing-a-winforms-window)

Comment: добавьте `else` и в него  `e.Cancel = true;`, да и в обработчике события у вас должен быть не просто `EventArgs e`, а какой положен быть.

Comment: Спасибо теперь моя игра прекрасна

Comment: В самом деле? Хотя, да, если из игры можно выйти, то она действительно прекрасна.

Comment: Нужно сделать так чтобы выход из игры был подарком в случае победы

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Должно быть как-то так:

```
void btn_close_Click(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (MessageBox.Show(this,
        "realy exit?",
        "closing program",
        MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
        MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
       this.Close();
    }
    else
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

> Свойство `CancelEventArgs.Cancel` - возвращает или задает значение,
>   указывающее, следует ли отменить событие.

Полезные ссылки:

- [How to prevent or block closing a WinForms window?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12873724/5275890)
- [Свойство CancelEventArgs.Cancel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.componentmodel.canceleventargs.cancel(v=vs.110).aspx)

P.S.: если решение вопроса найдено и оно может помочь в дальнейшем другим участникам сообщества - принято давать решение и отмечать его в качестве правильного. Особенно, если вопрос вполне уместен и не нахватал минусов.

Comment: `this.Close` не обязателен, так как мы и так закрываемся (`this.FormClosing += ...`). Здесь возможно вовсе однострочное решение: `e.Cancel = MessageBox.Show(...) != DialogResult.Yes;`.